# Why is the intersection of Omit<T, keyof U> and `U` not just `T`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Shouldn't `Omit<T, keyof U> & U` be equal to just `T`? Or am I missing something?

Here is an example, where this issue arises:

```
interface Bar {
  bar: string;
}

class Foo<T extends Bar> {
  foo(obj: Omit<T, keyof Bar>): T {
    return { ...obj, bar: 'bar' }; // compile error
  }
}
```

This is the error message from the Typescript compiler:

Type `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "bar">> & { bar: string; }` is not assignable to type `T`.
`Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "bar">> & { bar: string; }` is assignable to the constraint of type `T`, but `T` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `Bar`.

---

Of course one could simply cast it and it would work. Like so:

```
class Foo<T extends Bar> {
  foo(obj: Omit<T, keyof Bar>): T {
    return { ...obj, bar: 'bar'} as T; // this works
  }
}
```

But should this casting be necessary?

---

The expression `{ ...obj, bar: 'bar' }` is inferred to be `Omit<T, keyof Bar> & Bar`. But, after all, is that not an alias for `T`? How could `T` ever be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `Bar`?

To summarize,

if `Omit<T, keyof Bar>` is picking every member of `T`, excluding the one's existing in `Bar`,

How is the intersection of the types `Omit<T, keyof Bar>` and `Bar` not just `T`?

Comment: You can narrow individual properties like [this](https://tsplay.dev/QmbvBm).

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I completely missed that the `bar` member could be a subtype of string.